# How to update One to One relation Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using Asp .Net Core Razor Pages and i scaffolded a model using CRUD and generated me pages for create, edit, delete etc...

Problem is, all of them work except for edit.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }


        _context.Attach(Utilizador).State = EntityState.Modified;

     try
     {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!UtilizadorExists(Utilizador.UserID))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

whenever it hits save changes it gives exception of trying to insert

> SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object
>   'dbo.xColaboradores' with unique index 'IX_xColaboradores_UserID'. The
>   duplicate key value is (8). The statement has been terminated.

here is the models

```
public class Colaborador
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Utilizador")]
    public int ColaboradorID { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual Utilizador Utilizador { get; set; }

    public int DepartamentoID { get; set; }
    public virtual Departamento Departamento { get; set; }
}


public class Utilizador
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Colaborador")]

    public int UserID { get; set; } 

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public bool IsActivo { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UltimoAcesso { get; set; }
    public virtual Colaborador Colaborador { get; set; }
}
```

I tried attaching the related entities but it gives another exception

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'ColaboradorID' on entity type
>   'Colaborador' has a temporary value while attempting to change the
>   entity's state to 'Unchanged'. Either set a permanent value explicitly
>   or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this
>   property.

**EDIT**

I'm still not surely how this works on entity framework but it seems that it gets the object directly from the page that is binded.

I noticed that some properties had no values like the IDs of the related entity. they were at 0 hence why it was trying to insert. To fix this i had to put the primary and foreign Ids in a hidden input or it will try to insert them and gives exception duplicate

```
<form method="post">

    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Utilizador.UserID" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Utilizador.Colaborador.ColaboradorID" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Utilizador.Colaborador.UserID" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Utilizador.Username" class="control-label"></label>
        <strong class="text-danger">*</strong>
        <input asp-for="Utilizador.Username" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Utilizador.Username" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Utilizador.Colaborador.Nome" class="control-label"></label>
        <strong class="text-danger">*</strong>
        <input asp-for="Utilizador.Colaborador.Nome" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Utilizador.Colaborador.Nome" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Utilizador.Colaborador.Email" class="control-label"></label>
        <strong class="text-danger">*</strong>
        <input asp-for="Utilizador.Colaborador.Email" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Utilizador.Colaborador.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Utilizador.Colaborador.Departamento.Designacao" class="control-label"></label>
        <strong class="text-danger">*</strong>
        <select asp-for="Utilizador.Colaborador.DepartamentoID" asp-items="Model.DepartamentosList" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option value="">Selecione um departamento</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Utilizador.Colaborador.DepartamentoID" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-block text-white text-uppercase text-bold" style="background-color:#124475; box-shadow:0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 8px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and on back end

```
_context.Attach(Utilizador).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.Attach(Utilizador.Colaborador).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

with this i can change the related entity and it is updated normally.

Not sure if this is the best practice cause i tried changing the value on browser with dev tools and this can be easily hacked or if there is another way that it gets these values without storing them on input hidden but i noticed the generated scaffolded  item pages was already storing the primary key id on a hidden input.

Comment: how about changing your code to something like this `context.Entry(existingObject).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: this seems to work, no more expcetions, however it only updates the main entity, the related ones aren't if i change their values on the form

Comment: fetch the existingObject from DB and do `_context.Entry(existingObject).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedObject);`

Comment: where's is the instance of model received on update call?

Comment: i updated the post, please look. It's getting values from the binded properties on the page